# Determine number of consecutive identical points in a grid

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have dataframe and grid size is 12*8
I want to calculate the number of consecutive red dots (only in the vertical direction ) and make new column with it (col = consecutive red ) for blue it will be zero

for example

```
X y red/blue consecutive red 
1 1  blue    0
1 3  red     3     
1 4  red     3
1 2  blue    0
1 5  red     3
9 4  red     5
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[image]
Already have data for first 3 columns

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree 

red_points = df[df.red/blue== red]
blue_points = df[df.red/blue!= red]

tree = BallTree(red_points[['x','y']], leaf_size=40, metric='minkowski')

distance, index = tree.query(df[['x','y']], k=2)
```

Comment: Please share code you tried

Comment: I updated the post, I first tried to use Ball tree from sklearn to calculate the index and distance for each point to the red points then I stuck

Comment: **I think you need to clarify the expected output**. In your example about `[x,y]=# consecutive` you give `[1,3]=3` and `[1,5]=3` but `[1,4=0]` which seems wrong, it should either be `[1,4]=2` if you think `consecutive in any direction including current` OR `[1,4]=3` if you think `neighbours + current`. Also if all you're interested in is the list of red groups per x coordinates, there might be a less redundant output (ie for x=1 it would be [3], for x=9 it would be [2,5]).

Comment: [1,4] is 3 , it was typo, corrected now, output will consider  only in the vertical direction and including current one

Comment: Vertical in both directions right? Otherwise it would be [1,4]=2

Comment: yes both direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of such algorithm (there may very well be one), but **writing the algo isn't that hard** (I work with numpy because I'm used to it and because you can easily accelerate with CUDA and port to other data science python tools).

The data (0=blue, 1=red):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Generating dummy data for testing
ROWS=10
COLS=20
X = np.random.randint(2, size=(ROWS, COLS))
# Visualizing
df = pd.DataFrame(data=X)
bg='background-color: '
df.style.apply(lambda x: [bg+'red' if v>=1 else bg+'blue' for v in x])
```

[image]

The algorithm:

```
result = np.zeros((ROWS,COLS),dtype=np.int)
for y,x in np.ndindex(X.shape):
    if X[y, x]==0:
        continue
    cons = 1 # consecutive in any direction including current
    # Going backwward while we can
    prev = y-1
    while prev>=0:
        if X[prev,x]==0:
            break
        cons+=1
        prev-=1
    # Going forward while we can
    nxt = y+1
    while nxt<=ROWS-1:
        if X[nxt,x]==0:
            break
        cons+=1
        nxt+=1
    result[y,x]=cons
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=result)
df2.style.apply(lambda x: [bg+'red' if v>=1 else bg+'blue' for v in x])
```

And the result:

[image]

**Please note that in numpy** the first coordinate represents the row index (y in your case), and the second the column (x in your case), you can use [transpose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) on your data if you want to swap to x,y.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking thanks, the only doubt I have is my dataset is 96 * 2 (x & y coordinates ) rather than 12*8

Comment: if it's exactly what you're looking for you can mark my answer as correct. Dataset size doesn't matter as long as it remains 2D, if higher dimensions you would have to adapt accordingly, to make core more generically probably flatten the 3+ dimensions so the same code logic can scale up

Comment: Btw, that's the use case, curious to find out in which scenario such algo could be useful

Comment: here you created df with 19*9 and gave each cell a value (red / blue ) but i have 3 columns to use x, y and red/ blue , here i need to do .reshape(12, 8) but problem here is in some of the df i have less values then 96 (12*8) then it gives error

Comment: I will use this results in neural network  as a  new feature

Comment: I was more curious about the real-world aspect: what do these red/blue dots represent, and why is it important to count groups of red dots?

Comment: it is surface of a mechanical weld joint, red points represent small deformation and consecutive red points (in the vertical direction ) is something bad and it might ultimately cause cracks

Comment: I see, then in that case I think you might be better off leaving the learning of the feature representation to your network (it's one of the reasons why they are so powerful, hardcoding what you think is relevant or not self-defeating in a way). Eg you can represent your weld as an image (eg a heatmap representing the good/part parts of the welding, similar to my table output but just using the colors) and let the neural net figure it out. See https://github.com/fastai/fastbook/blob/master/01_intro.ipynb and the "Image Recognizers Can Tackle Non-Image Tasks" section.